# Why Hashmap values are getting replaced when duplicate key are used, even though it uses linked list for each bucket internally?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am revising concepts of HashMap and just wanted to check how linked list implementation of each bucket of Entry class works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(1, 2);
    map.put(1, 3);
    map.put(2, 1);
    map.put(2, 2);
    System.out.println(map.values());
}
```

}

Above code prints 3,2.
Shouldn't it print 1, 2, 3, 1, 2.

Comment: Thanks Tom, First link perfectly explains this. Please let me know how can i delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inserted the values `1, 2, 3` into key `1`, and the values `1, 2` into key `2`.  Each time you insert a value into a key, you *overwrite* the value which previously existed at the key, assuming there were a previous value.  So, your code is functionally identical to this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(1, 3);
map.put(2, 2);
```

That is, only the latest key-value assignments actually "stick."